# How to monitor all the processes from a user in windows server 2012?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, monitoring

I would like to monitoring all the processes which are invoked by a user within a period of time, like a couple of hours, some process may only run less than a second.

what is the best way to do?   Can I write a powershell script to monitor, or any tool from Microsoft or  sysinternals could help?

Answer (score 0):

Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.
I have used it and it definitelly shows new process creations and many other things. You can setup various filters and logging into file